# Can't play local video file

Tags: swift, tvos

I'm trying to play a local video using Xcode 7.1. All I want is for the video to load full screen on view and play.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class myClass: AVPlayerViewController {
    private func playVideo() {
        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(“video”, ofType: "mp4") {
            let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
            player?.play()
        }
        else {
            print("Oops, something wrong when playing video.mp4")
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        playVideo() 
    } 
}
```

Comment: if let videoURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("movie", withExtension: "mov") {
            player = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL)

Comment: Is it shown? Does the code run? Does it find the file? Explain what happens

Comment: so what's wrong? Please provide a problem statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a fix.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVKit

class PlayerViewController: AVPlayerViewController, AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func playVideo() {

        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("video", ofType: "mp4") {
            let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
            player?.play()
        }
        else {
            print("Oops, something wrong when playing video.mp4")
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        playVideo()
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide some explanation of the code and mark your own answer as the accepted the answer

Comment: So the fix was to add the AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate protocol?